# Query facebook for place (work,education) information

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

**Not the same as requesting workplace and education from the user**. I already requested that data and saved it. What I want is, given the ids, to query facebook as such `...?places=41241,32142...` and retrieve information such as `place id: 41241, name: NASA` regarding the input places... How exactly should this query be done? I didn't find anything about it... Thank you very much.

Comment: Please rewrite your question... It's not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Tobi sorry for the confusion. When I have access to the workplace of the facebook user I get an example of the following structure `Array
( [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [employer] => stdClass Object(  [id] => 251160061654471
                    [name] => Something Special
                )

            [position] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 110394418981692
                    [name] => Studying
                )
            [start_date] => 2018-01-01
        )
)` and **I keep the id**. how can i get the other information later by those id?

Comment: By requesting that id from the API …? `/251160061654471?fields={list of the fields you want}`

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have the place id, then make a GET request to `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/{place-id}?fields=location,name&access_token={your-access-token}`

Location data is documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/location/#Reading).

e.g. making this call to `/106078429431815?fields=location,name` gives:

```
{
  "location": {
    "city": "London",
    "country": "United Kingdom",
    "latitude": 51.5072,
    "longitude": -0.1275
  },
  "name": "London, United Kingdom",
  "id": "106078429431815"
}
```